# Import DataFrame XLS with variable structure with Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I received a couple of days ago a data set that is somewhat difficult to deal with, the only thing fixed that I see in this data set is that the records as such always start in row 9 and the names of the columns in row 7. As shows the picture below:

[image]

As you can see there are merged cells and the columns I highlighted are because sometimes they are not present in the structure, other times they are blank, and other times they show subtotals for each class.
Since the number of columns is variable, the algorithm I came up with was to first read up to the last column, which always contains the letters "CD", then I would remove the blank columns and those whose name contains the word "TOTAL".
As for the rows, they are not fixed for each file either, so I thought that it should only be read up to before the cell in column "A" that contains the word "TOTAL". They are a considerable number of files since each frame corresponds to a month of a specific year and I have to create a single base by concatenating all those frames by rows, which I would do with a pd.concat(list_dataframes, axis=0, ignore_index=True) . But for this I first need all of them to have a single structure. How could I read these types of files and make the changes mentioned?.
Thanks in advance for reading everything!

the expected output would be something like this
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to share the file so it can be downloaded? What is the expected output

Comment: Yes, but I don't have an option that allows me to upload the file so I can share it

Comment: Upload to Google drive or some other platform and share the link. Don't forget to include the expected output

Comment: Ok, this is the link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CarGmFWv31XbRrKasyP8nNk0igQQetI6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114347812860461842940&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: capture rows between `COMPANIES` and `TOTAL AF`, capture anything that ends with `Subclass`. CD can be ignored because it is the summation of each row. Am I correct so far? Am I to assume that this is generally what you want to capture from the other sheets as well?

Comment: Yes, it would be all rows between company and total AF (excluding total AF). Regarding the columns, they actually have different names, but for this case I named them SubClass. For each class they have the same three names (A,B,C), what I thought is that it is better to go through all the columns of row 7, until finding the combined Cell that always has the name "TOTAL CD"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matches all sheets in the file; i am basing this approach on our conversations in the comments. Have a look and see if there is room for improvement/better logic handling:

```py
df = pd.read_excel('Downloads/test.xlsx')
# get rows between Companies and TOTAL AF
top = df.index[df.eq('Companies').any(axis=1)].item()
bottom = df.index[df.eq('TOTAL AF').any(axis=1)].item()
# get rid of completely empty rows and columns, if any
temp = df.iloc[top+1:bottom].dropna(how = 'all', axis = 1).dropna(how='all')
# move the x,y,z columns as index, for easy reshaping
temp = temp.set_index(temp.iloc[:, 0].name)
# shift the row just above x as columns
temp.columns = temp.iloc[0]
temp = temp.iloc[1:]
temp.columns.name = None
temp.index.name = 'Companies'
temp.columns = temp.columns.fillna('TOTAL CD')
temp.reset_index()
  Companies A_Subclass1 A_Subclass2 A_Subclass3 B_Subclass1 B_Subclass2 B_Subclass3 C_Subclass1 C_Subclass2 C_Subclass3 D_Subclass1 D_Subclass2 D_Subclass3 TOTAL CD
0         X     3264371      228179      303407      300768       41407       40824      342168       37129       25354      749955        5615       15923  5355100
1         Y      259926       60609       85586         739         103         981      101961        2590        8842        3974           0           0   525311
2         Z     6788748      826830      642568       86356         471        4630      588506        3850       32907      767853       15176       62557  9820452
```